# react native expo crash after uploading image to firebase storage V9 (camera and image picker)

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native with firebase. When I try to save a post with picture picked in gallery or taken with iphone expo the app crashes.

My code:

```
const savePost =  async() => {

    if(!image) return;

    const path = `posts/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;

            // Create the file metadata
    /** @type {any} */
    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };

    const response = await fetch(image);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    
    // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
    const storageRef = ref(storage, path);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob, metadata);
    
    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + Math.round(progress) + '% done');
        switch (snapshot.state) {
            case 'paused':
            console.log('Upload is paused');
            break;
            case 'running':
            console.log('Upload is running');
            break;
        }
        }, 
        (error) => {
        // A full list of error codes is available at
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
        switch (error.code) {
            case 'storage/unauthorized':
            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
            console.log("// User doesn't have permission to access the object");
            break;
            case 'storage/canceled':
            // User canceled the upload
            console.log("// User canceled the upload");
            break;
    
            // ...
    
            case 'storage/unknown':
            // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
            console.log("// Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse");
            break;
        }
        }, 
        () => {
        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        });
        }
    );
    
}
```

The upload it's works perfectlty at 24% and the app craches, I have an iphone 11 and I am using Expo

Comment: Did you set the Rules to Verison 2? `rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}` AND try to delete this:  `const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    }; ` this shouldt be default and you cannot edit the systemmetadata like this.

Comment: about the metadata i deleted them, and for the rules

rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

and for android studio avd it's work perfetrly

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution without having to downgrade or anything. I was only using an image selector for this. I found that switching my quality from 1 to 0 also worked. I'm not sure why that is but hey, it helped me out for this one!

```
 import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
 import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const [pic, setPic] = useState(null);

const pickImage = async () => {
// No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 0,
});
const source = { uri: result.uri };
setPic(source.uri);
console.log(source.uri);
 };

const uploadImage = async () => {
const storage = getStorage(app);
const storageRef = ref(storage, "images");
const imageRef = ref(storageRef, "image.jpg");
const response = await fetch(pic);
const blob = await response.blob();
const snapshot = await uploadBytes(imageRef, blob);
console.log(snapshot);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been pulling my hair out for MONTHS trying to figure this out and I think I may have.

There are a few threads out there about commenting out the (clearGlobalTimeout) in the firebase storage package but that helped only about 15% of the time. On top of that, if I did manage to get a video uploaded, it would only be what seemed to be a short gif of the video I uploaded which is no bueno...

So after many suggested it, I moved to react-native-firebase and the crash would still happen. I've changed the quality to everything between 0 and 0.2,  changed Expo SDKs, RN SDKs, and everything else in between people would suggest and nada.

Eventually, I figured maybe the problem is likely in the file type and not providing metadata because when it would upload, the file type would be octet/stream. For iOS the app would crash if the image wasn't loaded on the device (a cloud photo). Android would upload far less frequently than iOS but would still have an occasional crash.

Finally, after just trying to work with what I could, I used Expo manipulateAsync() to save images as png and add file type in the metadata before upload and without fault, images uploaded every time whether they were physically on the device or in the cloud.

```
let metadata
let file
const newImage = await manipulateAsync(uri, [], {
      compress: 0.1,
      format: SaveFormat.PNG
})
metadata = {
      contentType: image/png
}
file = newImage.uri
const uploadTask.on = assetRef.putFile(file, metadata)


For videos, I was still facing problems. 
However after realizing images were working with that small fix, I tried this with videos: 

file =  image.localUri ?? image.uri
fileType = file.split(".").pop()?.toLowercase()

if (fileType === 'mov') {
      metaData = {
             contentType: "video.mp4"
      }
} .....

///For videos I chose the blob route

const res = await fetch(file)
const blob = await res.blob()

const uploadTask = assetRef.put(blob)
```

The last change I made was removing undefined keys from any object I upload to any firebase feature (firestore, storage, realtime, etc).

```
function removeUndefinedKeys(obj) {
        let newObj = {}
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (obj[key] !== undefined){
            newObj[key] = obj[key]
        }
    }
    return newObj
}


const wUndKey = {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    orientation: undefined
}

const newObj = removeUndefinedKeys(wUndKey)

// newObj = > { height: 100, width: 100 }

/// the undefined keys were more of a problem with Firestone obviously, 
however I chose to remove them before uploading to Cloud Storage as well just to be safe 
and account for that key missing on the front end if I have to.
```

After implanting those changes, it's been 3 weeks since I've had to deal with the problems mentioned in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still struggling with this issue, the answer may reside in the image quality during the upload to Firebase.

After quite a bit of digging, and similar to **@Rene Ortega**'s answer above, inside the `pickImage` function is a `quality` key that typically has a value of `1`. This means you'll be [compressing the image for maximum quality](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/). For some reason, this can cause your image to be uploaded at a much [larger size than intended](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3177), and in turn, cause your app to crash.

By changing the `quality` value to its default of `0.2`, I think you'll find that you can upload images without your app crashing.

Change:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
allowsEditing: true,
aspect: [4, 3],
quality: 1, >>>>>>>
});
```

To:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
allowsEditing: true,
aspect: [4, 3],
quality: 0.2, <<<<<<<<<
});
```

EDIT: I just learned that image type/size may also play a role in the crash. More info on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558113/how-can-i-add-image-type-and-size-restriction-while-using-expo-image-picker-lik).

EDIT: The quality of your image is not *visibly reduced*, only reduced in compression during upload.

Comment: This does not make much send, the underlying problem maybe the app is not able to handle higher image upload, but this could not be a solution, sometimes we don't want the quality to be compromised when uploading the image.

Comment: The underlying problem isn't technically known. This is simply offering a way to ensure that images will get uploaded without the app crashing, thus, addressing the OP's problem...

Answer (score 0):

I have found using just `uploadBytes` rather than any of the other options seems to work using v9.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Initially I found that uploads only work for .png images and it crashed for .jpg images. But I have managed to fix the issue.

You have to change the quality to its default which is 0.2 or change it to 0.
check here for reference about the quality https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickeroptions
**@Rene Ortega** and **@Josh** explain it better.